# Calling C# .NET methods from unmanaged C/C++ code

Tags: c#, c++, .net, clr, managed-c++

I need to call c# method in native c++. I followed [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/695387/Calling-Csharp-NET-methods-from-unmanaged-C-Cplusp) guide, download it, it's worked, but when I try it on new version of .net I cannot reproduce.
The main idea of this code is call c# method in such way:
C# .dll -> C++/CLI(managed c++) -> c++

C#

```
public static class ManagedClass
    {
        public static bool Check()
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Managed c++

```
namespace ClassLibrary1 {

    public ref class DoWork
    {
    public: bool CheckCSharp()
    {
        return CSharp::ManagedClass::Check();
    }
    };
}
__declspec(dllexport) bool Check()
{
    ClassLibrary1::DoWork work;
    return work.CheckCSharp();
}
```

c++

```
#include "ClassLibrary1.h"
_declspec(dllexport) bool Check();

int main()
{
    std::cout << Check();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

It's show error

> Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "bool __cdecl Check(void)"
> (?Check@@YA_NXZ) referenced in function _main
>
> 1 unresolved externals

Comment: *In your unmanaged project setting, you will need to reference the ManagedDll.lib file*.  The linker error says that you didn't take care of that.

Comment: @HansPassant But when I include header, this mean it's in the same directory, then it should be along with it, or not? I created an empty ClassLibrary1.h in native c++

Comment: A .h file can only take care of the declaration, it doesn't tell the linker what to do.  This is a detail that doesn't exist in C#, it doesn't use a linker and adding a reference to an assembly is enough to keep it happy, but needs to be taken care of explicitly in C++.

Answer (score 1):

[image] must write in linker path to .lib